# Should I use my transactions on the stored procedure level or on the middle tier level?

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, orm, transactions

We use an in house ORM where I work and in a lot of cases, we will need to do a number of different things in one transaction. Typically, I would wrapper a transaction in the middle tier around the whole thing, and hit success if it's all good.

The other option in our ORM is to build custom stored procedures which it just calls. I was wondering - would it be faster if I just made a custom stored procedure with a SQL transaction around it instead?

Wouldn't that be much faster? If so, why do most people choose the ORM route? I mean, having your database objects appear in the object model makes things really simple as it appears in intellisense, but is that the only reason why you would forgo performance for ease of use?

Answer (score 2):

Stored procs give you added performance benefits because of optimizations that the DB software can do with a known query. When you use ad-hoc queries, you lose this benefit.

I don't know your particular system, so I am not sure what is right for you. For us we found that pushing as much logic as made sense into stored procs on the DB layer allowed us to create a business logic layer using Views and Stored procs. This greatly simplified the coding effort and the data was always treated consistently.

Comment: really? see I always was told that this was "bad practice" to have business logic in SPs but I was never told why that was

Comment: Have you ever tried to scale a system that has all logic in the DB. It almost always FAILS. As the saying goes "hardware is cheaper than programmers".

Comment: Not all the logic, that would be using a shovel to hammer a nail. But a good portion of the logic in our case was well placed in the DB. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that a business transaction and a database transaction should be handled independently. I use the DB to do the CRUDS, and apply transaction management to those specific functions as necessary. In the middle tier you can also apply transaction management, but in a business scenarios and handle errors thrown at the database to control flow.

For example, if an insert fails in the database then an error is thrown and handled in the middle tier. From there it can catch the DB exception and execute proper steps to roll back other objects as well.

I feel this helps to keep the business logic where it belongs, and out of the data tier. Keeping this logic out keeps you data tier portable.

Comment: yeah, that's typically how I would do it too. But wouldn't that whilst it being much neater, perform much slower than just putting all the business logic in the SP?

Comment: Possibly, in the sense that rather than roll back two data transactions you would need to make a separate call to DB to roll back first item. However, I feel that putting logic in DB tends to be a record by record type of analysis and iteration, which is exactly the opposite of what most DBMS do well.